# Python - sys.stdout.buffer.write too slow - Video to ascii

Tags: python, terminal, ascii, stdout

I am creating a program to print in Ubuntu terminal Ascii frames from Video or Image.

My problem is quite delicate, because everything is fast enough except stdout to the terminal

---

For example this colored 400x100 Ascii 'image' from video has these results:

> -Total                              FPS: 1.5
>
> -sys.stdout.buffer.write(chararray) FPS: 2
>
> -calculation                        FPS: 20

[image]

in chararray are bytes of the resulting string composing 'one pixel'

Since the program is fast enough and I am slowed down only by **stdout** I have quite runned out of options.

**Is there some other alternative?**

Comment: `sys.stdout.write() `buffers the input and might not flush the input immediatly, you could use `print` instead of s`ys.stdout.buffer.write` or in order to make sure that it behaves like the print function, you should add:` sys.stdout.flush()`. That may help

Comment: well I just tried that and the speed result is the same - firstly flush and then I reshaped chararray, decoded and printed it. FPS print is the same

Comment: Is it possible that it is simply not limit of stdout but of the terminal?